# boost::uniform_on_sphere suddenly fails after a few million correct realizations, but only on certain hosts

Tags: gcc, boost, random, boost-random

## The Problem

After correctly generating random vectors in 2 dimensions for a while, the `boost::uniform_on_sphere` distribution suddenly generates a vector with values `-nan`.
I have tested the included program on three machines- the error was observed on two of them, but not on the third. Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on?

edit: It occurs on all hosts if the same type is used.

## The Hosts

### Host 1

- AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6174
- g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
- fails after 3802480 realizations

### Host 2

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         650  @ 3.20GHz
- g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)
- fails after 3802480 realizations

### Host 3

- Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D2700   @ 2.13GHz
- g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
- fails after 3802480 realizations, with slightly different output

### Realizations

On Hosts 1 and 2:

```
3802470: -4.8961880803e-01 , -8.7193667889e-01
3802471: 9.9225074053e-01 , -1.2425158173e-01
3802472: 6.5411877632e-01 , -7.5639182329e-01
3802473: -9.8332953453e-01 , -1.8183253706e-01
3802474: 7.1217632294e-01 , -7.0200067759e-01
3802475: -9.9968332052e-01 , 2.5166392326e-02
3802476: 9.9412262440e-01 , 1.0826008022e-01
3802477: -6.2786966562e-01 , 7.7831840515e-01
3802478: 5.7143938541e-01 , 8.2064425945e-01
3802479: 5.8261138201e-01 , 8.1275087595e-01
3802480: -nan , -nan
3802481: 9.2151606083e-01 , 3.8834002614e-01
3802482: 8.6448800564e-01 , -5.0265353918e-01
3802483: -9.1891586781e-01 , 3.9445358515e-01
3802484: -9.1544634104e-01 , 4.0244001150e-01
```

On Host 3, using `float` instead of `float_t`:

```
3802470: -4.8961877823e-01 , -8.7193661928e-01
3802471: 9.9225074053e-01 , -1.2425158918e-01
3802472: 6.5411871672e-01 , -7.5639182329e-01
3802473: -9.8332953453e-01 , -1.8183253706e-01  <- exactly the same as above
3802474: 7.1217626333e-01 , -7.0200061798e-01
3802475: -9.9968332052e-01 , 2.5166388601e-02
3802476: 9.9412262440e-01 , 1.0826008022e-01
3802477: -6.2786966562e-01 , 7.7831846476e-01
3802478: 5.7143932581e-01 , 8.2064431906e-01   <- slightly different
3802479: 5.8261138201e-01 , 8.1275087595e-01   <- exactly the same
3802480: -nan , -nan
3802481: 9.2151612043e-01 , 3.8834002614e-01
3802482: 8.6448800564e-01 , -5.0265347958e-01
3802483: -9.1891586781e-01 , 3.9445355535e-01
3802484: -9.1544634104e-01 , 4.0244001150e-01
```

## The Program

This was compiled simply with `g++ bug.cpp`. Turning on `-O3` optimizations did not change the result.

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_on_sphere.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    typedef boost::mt19937                                              GeneratorType;
    typedef boost::uniform_on_sphere<float_t>                           DistributionType;
    typedef boost::variate_generator<GeneratorType, DistributionType >  VariateType;
    typedef boost::circular_buffer<DistributionType::result_type>       BufferType;
    GeneratorType       gen;
    DistributionType    dist(2);
    VariateType         variate(gen,dist);
    const int           BUFSIZE = 10;

    gen.seed(11);
    BufferType buf(BUFSIZE);
    long n(0);
    while (1){
        cout << "n: " << n << "\r" << flush;
        DistributionType::result_type tmp = variate();
        buf.push_back(tmp);
        if (isnan(tmp[0])) {
            cout << "n: " << n << "       " << endl;
            cout << tmp[0] << " , " << tmp[1] << endl;
            ofstream fout("debug.out");
            for (int i=0; i<BUFSIZE; i++)
                fout << buf[i][0] << " " << buf[i][1] << endl;
            fout.close();
            ofstream gen_out("gen.out");
            gen_out << gen;
            gen_out.close();
            exit(1);
        }
        n++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does the output of host 3 match 1 and 2 even for the first few results?

Comment: Yes, the first 10 realizations are the same on all three.

Comment: It might be insightful to see the sequence around the 3802480th result for both the success and failure cases, to full precision (say, 8 digits and scientific precision). It sounds like one FPU is rounding something to 0/0. There are about 8 million bit patterns for the fraction part of a `float`, and you're suspiciously halfway through (although you wouldn't be seeing each one once). There could be a dud value.

Comment: Hmm could be, I'll get the output from all three hosts to full precision.

Comment: Ok, so the output is slightly different... which is a bit weird since I thought the RNGs stored `long int`s internally, which are not susceptible to round-off errors? Host3 is a 32-bit machine btw, could it be that `long int` is different for it?

Comment: Is the Atom build by any chance the only x86-32 build? Because one big difference between x86-32 and x86-64 is the difference between x87 (80 bits FP) and SSE (64 bits FP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to occur due to a bug in `boost/random/uniform_on_sphere.hpp`. In N dimensions, N normally-distributed numbers are generated as the components of an N-vector which is then normalized. In 2d, the probability of getting two zeros is apparently not negligible, resulting in the computation 0/0=`NaN` for each component due to the normalization.

A workaround would be to just program this distribution by hand for small dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

One big difference between x86-32 and x86-64 is the difference between x87 (80 bits FP) and SSE (64 bits FP). I.e. the 32 bits Atom has 16 extra bits to work in.

Comment: Ok, so that may explain the slightly differing numbers, but why am I getting a `NaN`? Am I just getting unlucky? Even with different seeds this eventually happens, so there must be a problem somewhere, right?

Comment: @rngantner: It indeed looks like a bug. NaN obviously does not lie on a unit circle.

Comment: I can "force" the error to occur on the Atom CPU by changing the `float_t` type to just `float`. Apparently the typedef is different on the two systems. But doing this results in the same error, even though some (not all) of the output is different. I updated the question with the new output.